# Formatting data returned via datareader

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, .net-3.5, formatting

I am returning a date from my database table:

```
objSQLDataReader("date")
```

Which gives me:

> 31/05/2011 16:00:50

How do I change this to:

> 31 May 2011

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
someDateInstance.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy")
```

Comment: I tried `objSQLDataReader("date").ToString("dd MMMM yyyy")` and got `input string was not in the correct format`.

Comment: @oshirowanen, you need to call the ToString method on a DateTime instance. So instead of `objSQLDataReader("date").ToString("dd MMMM yyyy")` use the correct call `objSQLDataReader.GetDateTime(objSQLDataReader.GetOrdinal("date"))..ToString("dd MMMM yyyy")`.

Answer (score 3):

```
((DateTime)objSQLDataReader("date")).ToString("dd MMMM yyyy")
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be a lot easier to **format it in your SQL** than to deal with it afterward.

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(25),GETDATE(), 106)
```

[Here's a whole list](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx) of date formatting choices.